# Android app crashes if destroyed by back button because of Parse exception

Tags: java, android, exception, parse-platform, runtime-error

In my `onCreate()` method I initialize the Parse library as suggested in their documentation:

```
// Init Parse and enable Local Datastore.
ParseObject.registerSubclass(AlertObject.class);
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, getString(R.string.parse_app_id),
            getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
```

However, if I press the back button (so the app is stopped and destroyed) and then I resume the app by clicking on it from the last used apps menu, it crashes throwing the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.app.pro/my.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`
[...]
```

Essentially, it suggests to invoke `enableLocalDatastore()` before `initialize()`, as actually I do.

Of course, if I override the `onBackPressed()` method as following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

the problem is solved because the app is not destroyed. BUT, why do I get that exception in the default behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move Parse initialization to the `onCreate` method of your Application class. If you don't have it you can create a class which extends from `Application`, example:

```
public class AppAplication extends Application {
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

      ParseObject.registerSubclass(AlertObject.class);
      Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
      Parse.initialize(this, getString(R.string.parse_app_id), getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
  }
}
```

And write in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file that you are using your own Application object adding the `android:name`attribute to the `<application>` tag. Example:

```
<application
    android:name=".AppApplication"
    >
```

Comment: Great, it works! Thank you so much! Do you think it is better to move also the other libraries initialization in the application class (e.g., Facebook, Google API, and so on)?

Comment: Yes, move there all initialization you have to do only once.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution works. Great! Thanks a lot!!